# visual studio 2019 and 2022 cummunity blocks with a text

Tags: visual-studio

visual studio crashes when I open a file, and I have to close it from the task manager.

The text that comes up: "Cannot navigate to the symbol below the collate symbol".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opz49.png)

and I almost can't drive... new and clean installation...

Comment: "Cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret."  We've got answers for that, just  google the English phrase.